# Why can't get the main window handle for a started process?

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc, process, ipc

I have a situation where I'm starting a process in my code in order to set up an IPC channel.  The process I'm starting is an MFC application with no CLR support.  The application from which I am starting this process is a C# module in a WPF application (thought I don't think that that is consequential to my problem).  This works with a version of the application that does support CLR, and it works on every computer except the deployment target, a touch screen computer with Windows 7.   But for some reason, when I try it with this exact scenario, the Process object never resolves a main window handle (`Process.MainWindowHandle`).   Is there another (perhaps even pinvoke) method of doing this?  Is this a security thing?  I'm the one staring the process.  The process's main window handle does exist.  I don't see what could be wrong.

If it helps, here is my code.

```
        _applicationProcess = new Process();
        _applicationProcess.StartInfo.FileName = _strProcessPath;
        _applicationProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = _strProcessArguments;
        _applicationProcess.Start();

        long nTicks = Environment.TickCount;
        if (_applicationProcess.WaitForInputIdle(1 /*minute(s)*/ * 60000))
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    // Don't let total processing take more than 1 minute(s).
                    if (Environment.TickCount > nTicks + 1 /*minute(s)*/ * 60000)
                        throw new ApplicationException("MFCApplication.Startup failed! The main window handle is zero!");

                    _applicationProcess.Refresh();
                }
                while (_applicationProcess.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() == 0);

                _applicationHandle = new IntPtr(_applicationProcess.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Do some stuff...
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Do exception handling.
        }
```

The `ApplicationException` is hit after a minute of trying to get a main window handle other than zero.

Comment: Have you tired using `WaitForInputIdle` as suggested by the MSDN docs? Also it's best practice to use `throw` instead of `throw ex`, as you will lose stack trace information with `throw ex` (`throw ex` restarts the exception throw and therefore stack trace).

Comment: @jordan I see your edit. You need to include @username in your comments so that the other user you are replying to is notified.

Comment: @jordan In your do\while loop I think you are confusing ticks with milliseconds. A tick is a 100 nanoseconds. It's probably more straightforward to use a `Stopwatch` for this.

Comment: @jordan It's probably worth considering putting a `Thread.Sleep` in your loop to throttle your `Refresh` calls.

Comment: @chibacity Nope none of that works.  And I didn't think the @ was necessary since you were the only commenter.

Comment: Is this a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: I have a theory, I hide the Main window shortly after it is loaded. Could the act of hiding a window demote it from main window status? Just a thought. @Hans Yes it is.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276439/reliable-way-to-wait-for-another-windows-process-to-redraw-its-main-window

Comment: @chibacity, for the record, according to the documentation `Environment.TickCount` is in milliseconds not ticks. Confusing name, but ticks used to be milliseconds.  I do like `Stopwatch` though.

Comment: @Jordon I stand corrected, `Environment.TickCount` is indeed in milliseconds and not ticks. That is confusing. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value you get out of Process.MainWindowHandle is unfortunately a guess.  There is no API function available to a program that lets it tell Windows "this is my main window".  The rule it uses is documented, it is the first window that's created by a process when it gets started.  That causes trouble if that first window is, say, a login window or a splash screen.

Not much you can do about this, you have to know more about how the program behaves to find that *real* main window.  Enumerating windows with EnumThreadWindows() could help you find it, as long as the first window was created on the same thread as the main window.  A more elaborate EnumWindows() will be necessary if that is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

My habit is to call EnumWindows in a loop combined with GetWindowThreadProcessId to find the window handle.

```
C Code, adapt to your language


DWORD TargetHWND;

//...
    while (EnumWindows(EnumWndProc, (LPARAM)(DWORD)pid)) {
        Sleep(100);
    }


//...

BOOL EnumWndProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    DWORD pid = (DWORD)-1;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    if (pid == (DWORD)lParam) {
        TargetHWND = hWnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: How does this help me exactly?  I'm trying to get a window handle from another process. Can you provide me with some code?

Comment: So basically this gets all of the windows for the given process ID, interesting.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get `MainWindowHandle` by means of your process, please make sure your WPF application is shown on the taskbar i.e `ShowInTaskbar="True"` and set `Application.Current.MainWindow` property to the window that you'd like to set as your main window.

If I execute code below in my WPF main window without setting `ShowInTaskbar="True"` I always got 0 as the `MainWindowHandle` because my WPF window was full screen and not displayed on the taskbar.

```
    Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
    var Query = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName");

    if (Query.Any())
    {
        Query.FirstOrDefault().Refresh();
        MessageBox.Show(Query.FirstOrDefault().MainWindowHandle.ToInt32().ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it could be different, but after you create the process, try doing:

```
Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("YourWindowTitle");
```

and see if any of the processes returned have a MainWindowHandle.

Comment: It is different, but in the opposite way.  Getting hold of a process this way, you don't have full trust and so can't do much of anything with it, and certainly not get its handle.  Only when you start a process can you interact with it in any meaningful sense.